# How to create a PDF report in Sonar?

Tags: pdf, report, sonarqube

1) I am new to Maven, so pls don't redirect me to "http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PDF+Plugin"

2) I have put/installed the PDF plugin jar "sonar-pdfreport-plugin-1.3.2.jar" in the "\sonar-3.7.4\extensions\plugins" location

Tell me, how to make the output of running Sonar come as PDF or some other type of report which can be simple shared over emails/offline without the SONAR GUI? Explanation in lay man terms would be easy, though more efforts from the writer.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed PDF Report in SonarQube in version 4.5.4 and PDF Report in version 1.4. The pdf is generated as a post job task by sonar-runner.

To see the report, make sure:

- Setup is configured to generate the report; and
- Project dashboard has the PDF Report widget visible.

I've run into some trouble for having force authentication with LDAP turned on, but if you remove the force authentication option everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that patching my [version with the correct code](https://github.com/lvilela/sonar-pdf-report/commit/1e5f746c3416b666233711ec4447f80455db1f36) with the GitHub code solved nothing.

With Apache Maven installed, you clone the repository and fix the issu in src/main/java/org/sonar/report/pdf/builder/RuleBuilder.java by adding the code after `SonarClient client = SonarClient.create(credentials.getUrl());`

```
.login(credentials.getUsername())
.password(credentials.getPassword())
.build();
```

After compiling and reinstalling it still fails miserably. It goes all the way into creating the temporary file needed to upload to the PDF Generator, but at the post job `POST` to `/pdf_report/store` server redirects the request with a `HTTP 302 REDIRECT` right back into the login page.

**EDIT:**
Found out that applying 3 patchs to the code solved the issu:

Patch 10:

```
    From 1e5f746c3416b666233711ec4447f80455db1f36 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
    From: i2slbv <Liliana.Vilela@i2s.pt>
    Date: Thu, 21 May 2015 15:19:37 +0100
    Subject: [PATCH] Fix for authentication exception in RuleBuilder.
```

Patch 11

```
    From e20b52644acc7d40e6383b25642e46bf905a8a21 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
    From: =?UTF-8?q?Micha=C5=82=20Dettlaff?= <mdettlaff@jitsolutions.pl>
    Date: Thu, 4 Jun 2015 16:11:40 +0200
    Subject: [PATCH] Related to SONARPLUGINS-3853 - Wrong use of sonar.branch
```

and patch 12

```
    From d0c408c1adf9bcd2560387ec8d5984c763b5d73b Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
    From: =?UTF-8?q?Micha=C5=82=20Dettlaff?= <mdettlaff@jitsolutions.pl>
    Date: Thu, 4 Jun 2015 18:48:43 +0200
    Subject: [PATCH] fix passing credentials when uploading PDF to the server
```

Now works perfectly.